# how can keyboard input from tcl to running bash script

Tags: bash, tcl

I want to start a bash script via Tcl.

While the bash script is running, an input field appears after about ~1 minute, so you have to enter something using the keyboard. I want to insert the variable `cc` there. How can I do that?

my tcl scrip:

```
bind pub "-|-" !ttest pub:ttest

proc pub:ttest {nick host handle channel arg} {

    set aa [lindex [split [stripcodes bcu $arg]] 0];
    set bb [lindex [split [stripcodes bcu $arg]] 1];

    set cc [lindex [split [stripcodes bcu $arg]] 2];

    set start [exec bash -c "su user -c \"cd /home/user/; bash teststart.sh $aa $bb\""]

    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :done"
}
```

this comes when I start the bash script directly in the console:

```
user@home:/$ cd /home/user
user@home:~$ bash teststart.sh testaa testbb
ENTER HERE:
(I would like to insert the variable cc here)
script done going exit
```

Comment: There is a one word answer for that:  `expect`.  An expect script (expect is TCL) will pretend to be the tty after launching a program (like ssh or in your case, bash).  Expect looks for patterns in the tty output and when it hits a match, it can take an action, like send some keystrokes as if they were typed from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an expect script that can perform what you are looking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# Put your bash specific command here - I just have bash for now
spawn /bin/bash

interact {

-o -nobuffer "ENTER HERE: "  {
        send $whatever
}

}
```

Sorry, I can't give you more - I don't actually use expect or tcl (well, not for many years) so I won't be much help to you.  I was just hoping to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you can just put the variable on the script's standard input. It'll wait there until the script is ready to consume it. You do that using `<<` with `exec`, which lets you feed a Tcl value straight in without any temporary files:

```
# We can call “su” directly; no need for a bash wrapper
set start [ exec su user -c "cd /home/user/; bash teststart.sh $aa $bb" << $cc ]
```

(The idea of hooking *anything* up to IRC that runs a script via `su` gives me collywobbles. I really hope your safety code is good!)

---

If you *need* to delay the sending of the string for a fixed amount of time, it's probably easiest to do that with a little subprocess pipeline:

```
set start [ exec bash -c "sleep 60; echo $cc" | su user -c "cd /home/user/; bash teststart.sh $aa $bb" ]
```

For more complex interactions, you're into the domain where the Expect extension is well worth it. I've no experience with integrating it with Eggdrop (and don't do much with Expect either; I have different problems for the most part).